# What is the best way to identify charts in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

The purpose of the program I am writing is to populate un-linked PowerPoint charts with data from excel. Currently I have labeled each graph by adding a title and then it's label.

ie. I know that on slide 6 the chart on the left will need to be populated with data that is labeled "IQ_45" in Excel and the chart on the right will need data from "IQ_46", so I added a chart title and labeled it "IQ_45" on the left and "IQ_46" for the right.

Since I don't use titles, this seems like the best way for me to do it. My idea is that I'll have the program search through each Slide -> each Shape -> if Shape is Chart -> If shape has Title -> read title text.

I have a feeling this isn't the best way though, and I'm looking for any other suggestions. Currently not looking for any code review, just some other, more educated ideas on how to achieve my goal of identifying graphs.

Questions I have on charts: Are you aware of any "special" interaction that chart titles may have with VBA? For example, must the chart title be visible and not hidden behind another object or shape for VBA to read it? If not, must it even be active for VBA to read it, or can you just set it then deactivate it? Any thing else?

Comment: Using the shape.name is the best way to be sure that the shape you want is the shape your code finds.  I have many macros that search each slide for specific shapes.   Titles are attributes of chart shapes and can be accessed by including the shape name is you definition.   You shouldn't need to activate any objects to access them.

Comment: @mooseman how do I set a Shape's name by hand? Aka, how would I be able to name my shape IQ_45 on slide 6 and then a chart on slide 80 Iq_46?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the ChartTitle is a chart element, not a Shape.

Comment: I would embed a textbox in each chart, call the textbox something like `txtSourceData`, then in the text of the textbox, I'd put the fully qualified range of data, like `C:\path\path\[workbookname.xlsx]SheetName!$A$1:$E$24`. Then I would set the .Visible property of the textbox to false.

Comment: @JonPeltier That seems really complicated to do everyday for 50+ charts, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @Pinlop It can be set in code, and retrieved in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name each shape "by hand", I use this macro.  Just select the shape.

```
Sub Nameit_PPT()
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
      .Name = InputBox("Enter Selected Shape Name")
End With

 MsgBox ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name

End Sub
```

Comment: So I must use VBA to name shapes? There's a little problem... I have people that build these "Shell decks" for me, and they don't know how to use macros... doesn't matter how simple... I must be able to do this without any VBA assistance. Just the "labeling" part.

Comment: In Office 365 or PPT 2016 Click on the object (textbox, shape, etc.) to select the object and in the  Format tab, click on Selection Pane in the Arrange group. From there, you'll see names of objects - you can  select any name and rename it.

Comment: what would be the difference? I have office 365 and other may have 2016... Mainly 365 is what I think though

Comment: If someone had office 2007 or 2010, finding the correct ribbon command may be difficult.

Comment: we can assume office 365. If needed we can update everyone computer, small office

Comment: Then you are good to go.  Test it out before you disseminate it to everyone else.

Comment: Oh! I just saw that you edited the comment. Perfect! This will work :). Thank you! To find this property its just .Name correct?

Comment: IF you do it without VBA, then you don't need the .name

Comment: I will be using VBA find the labels, not to label them. So someone will label the charts for me, and I will run VBA to add the data. The logic is still search through each Slide -> each Shape -> if Shape is Chart -> If shape has .Name -> read .Name text to identify chart correct? Or can I use some other method? Like For each slide -> search selection pane for "IQ_" -> if has "IQ_" then what is the chart associated with this

Comment: If each chart you want to reference starts with IQ, then you can search for that then determine which IQ_ chart to do whatever you want.

Comment: Office 2016 is the version of Office. Office 365 is the subscription scheme by which many users license Office 2016.